# load images from assets through XML

Tags: android, assets

I use in my application more than 150 images, and 30 icons ! so I find it a little bit messy to put those images all together in Drawable folder, and as it is impossible to have sub-folders in drawable , I am trying to load my images from the Assets folder. 
So to load images from assets programmatically its OK.

```
MY QUESTION is how to access Assets through XML?!
```

with drawable we use this :

```
  <ImageView    
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:src=" **@drawable/ic_rate** "
      />
```

So what is the equivalent using assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. An `ImageView` expects a drawable. Not all assets are drawables.

Drawables let you use images of different screen densities. Just use those. If you're struggling to stay organized, perhaps you could try using prefixes (e.g., prefix icons with `ic`). Another option would be to create a library project exclusively for icons, though it may be overkill.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the fact that you should use drawables, you can define your own `asset_drawable` attribute as string than override the `ImageView`to look for that atttibute and load the bitmap from assets. Your xml will be look like this

```
 <com.foo.bar.AssetImageView    
     android:id="@+id/img"
     android:layout_width="25dp"
     android:layout_height="25dp"
     app:asset_drawable="some/path/asset"
  />
```

Comment: Is it normal that it takes few seconds to load the images ?

Comment: @choco depends on the image size. Does it also takes that much time when you use drawables? If not you might be doing something wrong when loading image. Take a look at ImageView`s source to see how it loads the image.

Comment: It's a pity such universal API (to map an asset to a drawable resource) does not exist yet.